# Debug ASP.NET application hosted on shared server from my VS2010 IDE

Tags: asp.net, remote-debugging

i have web site and it is hosted on shared server ORCSWEB. now when i testing one page locally then i found it is running fine but when i test the same page putting our live site url then i found it is not working. so i want to test that from live site but from my own VS2010 IDE and want to set break point. i just do not know is it possible or not but i can not install any remote debugger there due to lack of access.

i visit this url for gudance http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio

but i could not help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Orcsweb customer, but you cannot do Remote Debugging unless the VS Remote Debugger service is running on the target machine. If I were a shared webhost then I wouldn't provide this service to my customers because it's a massive security liability.

Out of curiosity, why can't you fix it based on any exception reports generated right now?